# Succeeding in college often is a challenge for students,______, most college provide services designed to help students

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

*This question came in the Dhaka university admission exam 2018-19.*

> Succeeding in college often is a challenge for students,______, most college provide services designed to help students.

(a) moreover

(b) in addition

(c) therefore

(d) as a result

Firstly, the question sentence itself is wrong. It will be "colleges" instead of "college", and two independent clauses have ended and started with a [comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice). Anyhow, I think that (c) is the correct answer, but (d) could be correct as well, but the question bank says that the correct answer is (a).

Which is the correct option?

Comment: "College" should not be pluralized in this context. When referring to college in the abstract, it remains singular. For example, "many students drop out of college" or "a majority of students can't afford to go to school without taking out a loan" or "none of them had ever gone to university".

Comment: @Chungoli [I posted a question about this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/315403/146756). Check it out, if you want!

Comment: @Chungoli Maybe you're looking at the first instance of "college" in the question and not the second instance? I also looked at the first instance first...and the first instance should remain singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question bank answer of (a) is wrong. You are correct to say both (c) and (d) are correct. The services are provided mainly *because* many students have problems, so *therefore* is the logical answer. (D) also works as it has a similar meaning.

Comment: Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and [may be deleted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3294/18673).

Comment: The services are provided _because_ many students have problems, so _therefore_ is the logical answer. (d) would be possible as well.